# dbcontext not recognized while publishing to azure ASP.NET 5, dnx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an app that is working fine locally, but when I try publish it to azure, the db context is not recognized and I can't attach it while publishing, as in the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNIUo.png

Here is my WorldDbContext and Startup class:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPWya.png

I'm using EF7, and any help would be appreciated.